# AdGuard блокирует некоторые элементы сайта

Tags: html, css

Сделал себе портфолио, а в footer сделал ссылки на мои страницы и как назло AdGuard их начал блокировать. Когда выключаю, то они появляются обратно, а когда включаю его на своем сайте, то ссылки пропадают.

```css
footer {
 background-color: #3a7dfd;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding-top: 60px;
 padding-bottom: 110px;
}

.footer-author {
font-size: 24px;
margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.development-of-sites-turnkey {
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-top: 0px;
}

.social-block {
 text-align: center;

}

.social-block a {
 display: inline-block; /* Посмотреть что за значение */
 margin-right: 13px;
 margin-left: 13px;
}

.footer-button {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #fff; /* Спросить в чате */
background-color: transparent; /* Прозрачный цвет */
color: #fff;
font-size: 18px;
border-radius: 50px; /*Скругление */
padding: 12px 40px;
-webkit-transition: 0.2s;
-o-transition: 0.2s;
transition: 0.2s;
}

.footer-button:hover { /* Анимация */
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #3a7dfd;
}

.footer-feedback {
 margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.footer-feedback-block {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<footer>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <h4 class="footer-author">Ярослав Салимов</h4>
    <p class="development-of-sites-turnkey">Разработка сайтов под ключ</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="social-block">
     <p>Подпишитесь:</p>
    <a href="#"><img class="animated bounceInUp" src="socials/facebook-logo-button.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="animated bounceInUp" src="socials/telegram-symbol.png" alt="Telegram"></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="animated bounceInUp" src="socials/vk-social-logotype.png" alt="Vkontakte"></a>
    <a href="#"><img class="animated bounceInUp" src="socials/youtube-symbol.png" alt="YouTube"></a>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="footer-feedback-block">
    <p class="footer-feedback">Напишите мне:</p>
    <button class="footer-button">Написать</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
 </div>
 <!-- /.container -->
</footer>
</body> 
</html>
```

[image: Включен блокировщик рекламы]
[image: Выключен блокировщик рекламы]

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. Чтобы исправить ситуацию нужно изменить классы в тегах  т.к. блокировщик блокирует именно класс, который я указал.

Comment: Я вам так скажу, эти кнопки **должны** быть скрыты блокировщиками социальных виджетов.

Comment: Стоит уточнить, какой именно класс.

Comment: Это не ответ. Как изменить, где изменить - не написано.